# Linq query returning null where debugger shows value

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, linq, .net-core

As you can see from the below the immediate window is showing the second element should be returned from my Linq query:

[image]

It works if I call it on ToList() but curiously it works without this on a nearly identical function I have to get the `MasterHeader`.

I'm running .NET Core 6 in VS2022 and was wondering if there was any memory or cache issues that could cause this?

The complete function is here for reference:

```
private static PageIdentity GetNearestMasterPageFooter(TreeNode currentPage)
{
    var masterPage = currentPage.Parent;
    while (masterPage.ClassName != MasterPage.CLASS_NAME && !masterPage.IsRoot())
    {
        masterPage = masterPage.Parent;
        if (masterPage == null)
            return null;
    }

    var children = masterPage.Children.ToList();
    var test = masterPage.Children;
    var masterFooter = masterPage.Children
            .Where(p => p.ClassName == MasterPageFooter.CLASS_NAME)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    return masterFooter?.ToPageIdentity();
}
```

Comment: Could something be going on asynchronously? As in the data changes before the debugger gets the breakpoint but after the other lines execute?

Comment: I don't understand, can you reformulate?

Comment: It is not clear your question.
1 - What is test[1]?
2- What data masterPage has? And what is inside Children?

Comment: The reason it works on ToList could be that this fixes the elements at that point in time. But then the `Children` collection could be getting modified elsewhere prior to the Linq query.

Comment: @PeterMoore I've added the complete function which I think should rule out anything happening to the data at a different time but I think maybe you are putting me on the right track all the same. Thanks

Comment: Ah ok cool. I don't know Forms well but usually being all UI-code *should* usually rule out asynchronous shenanigans. I don't see a `Children` property on `TreeNode` so I'm not sure where that's coming from. But whatever `Children` is, it's possible its `Enumerator` is weird and returns different values in a Linq query than it would using the array indexer. That's all I got!

Comment: @PeterMoore TreeNode is from the Kentico CMS, but thanks for the hint regarding its Enumerator being weird, I'll get them to have a look at it, might be they're the culprits rather than .Net Core or Linq!

Comment: Hello, is there any update on this issue？ Are they not related to .Net Core or Linq?